# Unmanaged network icon - Network manangement disabled

Tags: network-manager

I was having problems connecting to the internet either by wireless or wired connection.
I keep getting an icon in the systray that has a tooltip that says "unmanaged" and when I click on it I get a "Network management disabled".

I googled and found the command:

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

Which finally enabled my network and I have net. The problem is I still get the icon with the some word "unmanaged"

Can anyone help me out? I just want to know what is happening and why did I had to go to the command line to enable my network.

I had to put the computer in sleep mode and then it wouldn't wake up, so I rebooted the machine. The network manager problems started again, this time the file mentioned by maco had the value set to true and it still wouldn't work.

Anyone know how I can make this permanently work? I did a

```
sudo init 0
```

And when I booted the machine at a later time I had the network manager enabled.
Have no clue why.

Comment: For problems in 16.10, please see [Ethernet device not managed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/882806/ethernet-device-not-managed).

Comment: I installed desktop on Ubuntu server: to solve I followed instructions on this post: https://www.raytechnote.com/wired-unmanaged-after-install-ubuntu-desktop-gui-on-ubuntu-server/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I find this happens after a bad shutdown.  Just change

```
managed=false
```

to

```
managed=true
```

in `/etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf`

---

**Note:** In newer versions of Ubuntu, the file is at `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Then restart service

```
service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I edited the file, rebooted and it worked great :) Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I edited the question to add that the same thing has happened again and your solution unfortunately doesn't seem to work any more. I had to switch to gnome to use the wireless connections available :(

Comment: maco's solution now requires editing of /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf. The setting is still the same.

Comment: After changing the .conf file you have to restart the network manager. For Debian/Ubuntu issue this command: sudo service network-manager restart

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me in 16.10.

Comment: worked for me 18.04

Comment: Instead of rebooting, `service network-manager restart` will also work.

Answer (score 15):

This worked for Ubuntu 17.04

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Oh jeez this had been plaguing an installation of Bionic I did on ZFS using debootstrap for hours, I was beginning to think nothing would ever work.  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: worked also on Ubuntu 18.04 in which the NetworkManager suddenly stopped.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. Ubuntu 20.04. Probably bad Software Updater package caused no wired connection...

Answer (score 9):

I've just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10. After that, this problem started to happen to me. In my case, I've solved it following the suggestion given in [Ubuntu's launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1638842/comments/6):

```
touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
```

This creates an empty file.

Comment: I had the same problem and only this helped me!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me finally fix this problem after an upgrade to 17.04.

Comment: Thanks, this was the only solution that worked for me in 18.04

Answer (score 8):

You should look at the contents of the file `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state.` It should look something like this:

```
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

Change any from 'false' to 'true' to re-enable networking. It may work better if you first stop NetworkManager:

```
sudo stop network-manager
```

And start it again once done. Or reboot :)

In any case, this is frequent when a suspended system fails to wake up. It should be fixed in Maverick.

Comment: +1 Massive help for me... Thx.  Countless hours fiddling with network settings until I decided to hit the stack exchange.  Silly me.

Comment: This! I've been stuck on this all day! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10. I have 3 network cards (all configured) and no Wifi. All 3 cards were disabled, all options on the Network Manager menu were greyed out, so clicking them does nothing. I fixed it by combining two of the solutions above:

Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and change:

```
managed=false
```

to

```
managed=true
```

Restarted network-manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

No change. Then I tried:

```
touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo service network-manager restart
```

All three network cards came back on-line.

Comment: the fix is weird, and the post above is not exactly correct.

Comment: After a lot of research this was the only one that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking the NetworkManager icon and enabling the network from that menu.

Comment: It doesn't work. I just get a "Network management disabled"

Answer (score 0):

I installed `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` to ubuntu server 14.04.4 and the file was not 
`nm-system-settings.conf`, but 
`NetworkManager.conf`

As in `sudo gedit etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
I could not find `nm-system-settings.conf`
Perhaps it is not installed (*nm-system-settings*) as I do not see it on the gnome Panel bar in the gnome classic view desktop. Need to get the Network going to do updates and install `gnome-session-flashback` to get the Gnome-Flashback (Metacity) on 14.04.4 LTS, my Favorite desktop!

I had not checked `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state` before reboot but, perhaps it was updated after reboot as it was correct.