# Network Manager stops working after an update to ca-certificates

Tags: network-manager

Fresh Beta install on Aspire 5741 (NEW70) - network ok

After installation, run update (485 updates) - install completes ok

After update and reboot, Network Manager fails to open. Unable to connect to LAN.

Though my hardware, both WLAN and LAN, are still recognised, however network icon disappears from taskbar, and I am unable to launch NM-APPLET both from menu and terminal.

Error "missing folder" in terminal

Tried both the amd64 and i386 versions.

Ubuntu 10.10 runs fine on laptop.

Comment: 11.10 is a `beta` so any problem you get is likely to be solved with the final release. You need to inform the maintainer of the package if you want this fixed (ie -> launchpad ).

Comment: Please take a look at this link and follow the instructions given there when you have [issues with Alpha/Beta releases](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)

Comment: You probably got bit by the ca-certificates bug, see this discussion for help: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1847446

Comment: Don't edit your question body to have the answer. Instead just use the "Your Answer" box to enter what resolved it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same happened to me this morning.
You can activate yout network like this:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo dhclient eth0
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

After that you can start a partial upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f
```

If this doesn't work look here:

[Network-Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2901/unmanaged-network-icon-network-manangement-disabled)

Answer (score 6):

You may as well try to run this command from the terminal as this worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnss3:i386 libnss3
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you have tried, but you could run nm-applet from the run dialogue, and it should start your networking icon. If it does not start, run:

```
sudo start network-manager
nm-applet & disown
```

In a terminal.

Edit: Jorge pointed you to the right place.

Comment: I get that error:
`mark@nexar-laptop:~$ sudo start NetworkManager
[sudo] password for mark: 
start: Unknown job: NetworkManager
mark@nexar-laptop:~$ sudo start network-manager
start: Job is already running: network-manager
mark@nexar-laptop:~$ sudo nm-applet & disown
[1] 2018
mark@nexar-laptop:~$ nm-applet: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
`

Comment: @MarkGreenwood: uh oh... You upgraded libnss3...

Comment: So what am I supposed to do ? :\

Comment: @MarkGreenwood follow the forums link I linked to on top.

Comment: @JorgeCastro So I copied libnss3.so to x86_64-linux-gnu and I rebooted. Now am I supposed to delete it ? I don't know what to do... Sorry I'm really not good in Ubuntu :(

Answer (score 1):

According to the link that Jorge Castro provided - [SOURCE page 2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1847446&page=2) you can follow the advice given on [post #14](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11270659&postcount=14) or [post #13](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11270651&postcount=13)

According to [Post #14](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11270659&postcount=14) - you will have to boot off a live disc, mount the Ubuntu partition, chroot into it and then perform updates, the new updates contain the fix for the  *ca-certificates* bug. For a detailed how-to please take a look at the post.