# Wired connection disconnects randomly

Tags: networking, 20.04, wired

After updating ubuntu 16 to ubuntu 20.04.1 the wired connection keeps disconnecting randomly.

The solution is manually turn off and on the connection from the upper left button. However, I am working remotely and that is not an option anymore.

I have tried solutions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2901/unmanaged-network-icon-network-manangement-disabled) but they do not work for me.

This is the output of some commands that I think they might be useful when the connection is **not** working:

ifconfig:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::896d:d145:fe49:db08  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a0c:5bc0:40:1028:df60:8e5c:3fb0:a0dd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a0c:5bc0:40:1028:60f4:f459:9371:5e6e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a0c:5bc0:40:1028:4597:f3aa:b00c:62bb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 18:60:24:8b:fe:32  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 65344897  bytes 10798738778 (10.7 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1644328  bytes 1140060185 (1.1 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf3100000-f3120000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 90170  bytes 10380905 (10.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 90170  bytes 10380905 (10.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

nmcli d:

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION        
eno1    ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

nmcli:

```
eno1: connected to Wired connection 1
        "Intel Ethernet"
        ethernet (e1000e), 18:60:24:8B:FE:32, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default, ip6 default
        inet6 2a0c:5bc0:40:1028:4597:f3aa:b00c:62bb/64
        inet6 2a0c:5bc0:40:1028:60f4:f459:9371:5e6e/64
        inet6 2a0c:5bc0:40:1028:df60:8e5c:3fb0:a0dd/64
        inet6 fe80::896d:d145:fe49:db08/64
        route6 2a0c:5bc0:40:1028::/64
        route6 ::/0
        route6 ff00::/8
        route6 fe80::/64

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536
```

**EDIT**

I set `managed=false` in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and reboot. This is the output of some commands when the connection **is working**:

cat /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

sudo lshw -C network:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 05
       serial: 18:60:24:8b:fe:32
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=155.198.45.81 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:33 memory:f3100000-f311ffff memory:f313b000-f313bfff ioport:2040(size=32)
```

**EDIT**

These are the captures of the wired settings:

[details tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZEPO.png)
[identity tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPRcD.png)
[IPv4 tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juNfI.png)
[IPv6 tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z47JJ.png)

**EDIT**

This is the output of `ls -al /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired*`:

`-rw------- 1 root root 261 Nov 16 16:06 '/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 1.nmconnection'`

Comment: You're not getting an IPv4 address. /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf should have "managed=false". Then reboot. And "Wired Connection 1" indicates that there must be a "Wired Connection". Connect to that one, edit settings if required, and delete "Wired Connection 1". Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Thanks for the info... however... as you can see, when placed into the comments, they're unreadable. Please delete the 3 comments, do the commands again, and edit the output into your original question. Thanks. Let me know when you've done it. Remember to start comments to me with @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema Hi, you are totally right. I do not know how to remove "Wired connection 1", I can only see one wired connection in settings. Thanks