# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS - Wired network connection randomly breaking until reboot

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, internet, ethernet

I have a mini PC I use as a home server running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I've had it for several months now with no issues but as of a week or so ago it has started randomly losing connection to my network. It is on a wired connection but it just loses connection and acts like it is not plugged in.

I've tried:

- Turning wired connection on/off in the settings
- Removing and reinserting the network cable in the server and the router

Nothing seems to fix it except rebooting.

Potentially relevant details:

- I install updates and reboot each night so it could be caused by a recent update
- It's connected via a network switch (however the other devices on the switch work fine)
- It uses a static local ip
- Kernel version: 6.2.0-26-generic (this may have updated recently as I think I was on 5.something last time I checked)
- Wifi is usually switched off but it seems to work fine if I turn it on

Appreciate any info or suggestions of what logs to look at to find out whats happening, thanks.

Edit: I've checked my upgrade logs and this issue first happened on Monday which seems to be when the kernel was updated, so potentially the kernel upgrade caused some problems. Before that I was on `5.19.0-50-generic` so I may try downgrading if this continues and I can't find any other fix

Comment: Did you try a different cable? A different port on switch? A different switch?

Comment: @mpboden I dont have any other switches or cables, plus the fact that rebooting without touching anything fixes the issue makes me pretty confident its a software issue

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Everything you mention about your setup is the same for me. Issues started last week. Using iPerf, my wired connection between my ubuntu 22.04.3 box (kernel 6.2.0-33-generic) and my Mac hovers between 10-15Mbps for a few hours and then eventually disconnects. Weirdly, I have duplicate hardware running fresh install of 20.04.6 (5.4.0-163-generic) also experiencing the same issue. What seems to happen is the connection slows, and then eventually I get a question mark over the LAN icon in the menu bar and the connection drops. A workaround I've found, to continue

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308988/wired-connection-occasionally-disconnects-ubuntu-20-04-1 this could also be related to this issue, but as the post is a bit older it might be just a completely separate issue.

Comment: weird.. the same happens to me on debian 11 Linux kernel 6.1.0-12-amd64. Since a few days ago. Wifi works

Comment: I am having similar issues on 22.04.4 with kernel 6.5.0-21-generic. Most of the time, the wired network works just fine, however, sporadically it seems down. During these phases ping reports 100% packet loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same issues as you, which started about a week ago. I tried to do a system update yesterday, but lost connection a few hour later. I did a downgrade on my kernel this morning (**5.19.0-50-generic**) and for now, I haven't had the issue since

Comment: Downgrading my Kernel worked! Still no crash for now

Comment: Accepting this as I did the same and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The network naming has changed at the installation. Cards named previously in 5.15 ens<x>f<y>np<z> with 22.04 are named with the new installer ens<x>f<y>.
The same behavior applies with the linux-generic-hwe-22.04, and drops all network connections at the first reboot.
Hence you would need to rename manually in /etc/netplan/00-... the network cards and then reboot. I am putting a bug report at ubuntu right away.

Answer (score 0):

I started having the same issues this week.  I did a full update today and I haven't had the issue since.  Knock on wood.

Comment: Good to know it's not just me. I'm a bit of a linux rookie, when you say "full update" what exactly did you do?

Comment: Hey buddy.  Did a sudo apt update / install -y.  Still working.  It was super frustrating because my wifi would work but not wired.  I had to restart in the middle of work.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't say the same, I made sure I updated everything possible today and then it happened again within like an hour, will probably try downgrading my kernel later.

Comment: One idea that just rattled around my head.  What if you find the driver for the network card, delete it, reinstall it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also, and I tried so many things, and nothing helpep, and then I just disabled the Security boot option, and then my issue was solved.
Maybe it can help someone else